# Postgres Table Size is much larger than the Excel file

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, size

I have an Excel file of around 3.3MB. After loading the file into Postgres, I get the table size of 19MB using the function pg_table_size(). Why the table size is so much larger than the excel file even though I have excluded the size of the indexes?

I tried to use pg_table_size instead of pg_total_relation_size but the size is still way bigger than the excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel xlsx files are zip files and are therefore *compressed*.

If you try saving the data as a CSV text file you'll likely also find it's a lot larger.